# Javascript Timezone Change

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.2

I made small JS app using Sencha Touch/ExtJS. It display some date values taken from database. But those date get changed depending on client's time zone.

How can i stop automatic time and date change and display values as i enter ?

Answer (score 1):

use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/), it handles all kind of timezone issues.

Comment: Can you explain bit more ?